# Processing.js shape not working

Tags: javascript, function, processing.js

I have a function that I wrote to draw a polygon with any number of sides. However, when I run it in Java-script only, it doesn’t work. Why?

```
    function sketchProc(processing) {

function polygon (sides, centerX, centerY, radius, fillColor, strokeColor) {
    processing.fill(fillColor);
    processing.stroke(strokeColor);
    var innerAngle = 360/sides;
    var rotationAngle = innerAngle;
    processing.beginShape();
    for (var i = 0; i < sides + 2; i++) {
        processing.vertex(centerX + radius*Math.sin(rotationAngle), centerY + radius*Math.cos(rotationAngle));
    console.log(centerX + radius*Math.sin(rotationAngle), centerY + radius*Math.cos(rotationAngle));
        rotationAngle = innerAngle * i;

    }
    processing.endShape();
}}
```

It just draws a weird zigzag shape. (I implement this function later in my code and it works okay, just the shape is messed up.)

Comment: Can you please post a link to a JSFiddle or a CodePen running your code?

Comment: @KevinWorkman The canvas and external scripts didn’t work when I input them.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. We need to be able to run the code. The best way to do that is to put together a JSFiddle or a CodePen.

Comment: My canvas element doesn’t show up when I run the code in either of those; no canvas is displayed in the results view.

Comment: Can you please fork an example like [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n2yUg/), modify with your changes to demonstrate the issue and then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44167589/edit) your question to contain the link to the updated version? That way we can see the issue.

Comment: @JoeEdrick You need to go through the proper setup steps. And you need to include the code that actually calls your `polygon()` function. What you're seeing is exactly what we would see if we copied your code. That's why we're asking you to put together a JSFiddle or a CodePen.

Comment: @SamOnela Thanks for the demo! Here’s an example of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/nebrelbug/wzwchuht/  It works fine in, for example, Khan Academy’s ProcessingJS projects.

Comment: "_when I run it in Java-script only, it doesn’t work_" - what exactly does that mean? are you running it without processingJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, you might want to edit your question itself instead of just commenting with a JSFiddle. You might also @reply each person who asked for it. Otherwise we won't see it! Anyway, thanks for putting it together.

Take a look at this line:

```
processing.vertex(centerX + radius*Math.sin(rotationAngle), centerY + radius*Math.cos(rotationAngle));
```

Notice that you're feeding `rotationAngle` into the `sin()` and `cos()` functions. Also notice that `rotationAngle` is specified in degrees. (Values between 0 and 360.)

This works okay on Khan Academy because by default their functions take degrees.

However, normal Processing and Processing.js take arguments in **radians**! (Values between 0 and 2 PI.) So you have to convert your `rotationAngle` variable into a radian value! You can use the handy `radians()` function to do that.

More info can be found in [the reference](http://processingjs.org/reference/radians_/).